# Database compatible countdown

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, timer

I'm looking to create a 15 min countdown that is being displayed when the button start is pushed, but that it is also accessible from different computers. Meaning it doesn't restart when you refresh, or log in in a different computer. 
My logic was something like this...

```
$start = datetimestamp(h:i:s);
$end = datetimestampt(h:i:s) + 900 ;
$countdown = $end-$start

echo $countdown;
```

However, the timestamp is giving me a lot of issues, and the $countdown is not live. 
I'm thinking this has to be strictly php for it to work with MySQL (so that the timestamp doesn't refresh).

I have this in JavaScript which basically is just a countdown of 15 minutes that gets activated when the button is clicked, however it does restart every time the page is refreshed or accessed from a different computer. And I can't figure out how to store a variable into a database...

```
var seconds = 900;
var t;

function secondPassed() {
var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
}
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
```

}

```
function countdown() {

// starts countdown
secondPassed();
 if (seconds != 0) { 
    seconds--;
    t = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
    changeColor();
    }
}

function cdpause() {
// pauses countdown
clearTimeout(t);
};

function cdreset() {
// resets countdown

cdpause();
secondPassed();


};
```

I appreciate any help or guidance you can give me! I've gone through some tutorials, but it doesn't match the requirements I have. If it matters I'm trying to have different timers that may start at different times and all need to be recorded an displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic.

When the button is clicked, store the start and end times in the database.

When you are displaying it, use the end time and **current time** to display the timer. You can use the javascript to display the timer.

In this way, you will be able to show the same timer in different systems without restarting it.

To store a value in the database , google it. There are many tutorials online to help you understand inserting data into mysql database using php

Comment: Well my problem is exactly that, storing that javascript value unit MySQL. How do I transfer that into PHP?